# Attach and detach affixed headers with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm trying to use the affix function to attach a header to the top of the screen, but have it attached only for a portion of the page. It should detach (and scroll up along with the content) when the user scrolls past a certain point.

I'm using the script from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uaa3U/198/).

What I'm trying right now is this:

```
$('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

$('#nav').affix({
    offset: $('#nav').position()
});
$('#nav').detached({
    offset: $('#bottom').position()
});
```

With the `.detached` class like so:

```css
.detached { position: static; }
```

Can't get this to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is possibly with the standard Twitter Bootstrap affix module.

Comment: I think you are looking for a question [answered here.][1] Check out the fiddle.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197453/affix-div-to-bottom-of-window?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Twitter Bootstrap affix module doesn't have that option. But, I've used many times [hcSticky](http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/), it is awesome. Take a look, it's simply to use and works very well.

Comment: IT is possible with bootstrap and js

Comment: "With bootstrap and js"... That means - use bootstrap, but also change provided js code and create your own. If OP could do that, he never ask this question. So I pointed out on small script, simple to use.

Comment: @Shail How is it possible with twitter-bootstrap? I'd like to avoid having to use another lib (such as hcSticky or jsfiddle).

Answer (score 3):

You can write the logic in a function, and pass it to affix as offset.top.

Try

```
var navHeight = $("#nav").height();
var detachTop = $("#detach").offset().top;
var navTop = $("#nav-wrapper").offset().top;

$('#nav-wrapper').height(navHeight);
$('#nav').affix({
    offset : {
        top : function() {
            if ((navHeight + $(window).scrollTop()) > detachTop) {
                return Number.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            return navTop;
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/BuNq2/)

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed. Multiple navbar version right here: http://jsfiddle.net/BuNq2/5/

Answer (score 2):

Another option which might work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/5n9vw/

**HTML**

```
<div class="header" data-spy="affix">
affixed header, released after scrolling 100px
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
var y = $(window).scrollTop();
if( y > 100 ){
  $(".header.affix").css({'position':'static'});
} else {
  $(".header.affix").css({'position':'fixed'});
}
});
})
```

Good luck!